# Why isn't express cookie-parser parsing all my cookie data?

Tags: cookies, express, socket.io, authorization, session-cookies

I'm attempting to parse signed cookies from within socket.io for authorization.  I've set up a simple method to do so, making sure to use the same cookie secret in both my express & socket.io configuration.  However, when parsing the cookies, I only see the "io" cookie get parsed and not the "sid" cookie (the one from express).

```
var config = require('config');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var ioCookieParser = function () {
  var parser = cookieParser.apply(null, arguments);

  return function (socket, next) {
    console.log('Parsing cookies:', socket.request.headers.cookie);

    parser(socket.request, null, function () {
      console.log('Parsed cookies:', socket.request.cookies);
      console.log('Parsed signed cookies:', socket.request.signedCookies);
      next();
    });
  }
};

io.use(ioCookieParser(config.server.cookieSecret));
```

In looking at the output from the `console.log` lines, I see:

```
Parsing cookies: io=F2sP36OJqG35eon3AAAA; sid=s%3AoiVZO8uT6XEqZ7I149JMa0Vt0ebh_RMV.85jPEnUODVqcW100BuZankaJyqLLoEJ06goRgj6QK5I
Parsed cookies: { io: 'F2sP36OJqG35eon3AAAA' }
Parsed signed cookies: { sid: false }
```

You can clearly see in the first output line that `sid` is defined in the cookie.  However, it's not being parsed out as can be seen in the second output line.  What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I didn't realize that signed cookies are in a separate `request.signedCookies` object, but I'm now seeing that it's setting `{ sid: false }` instead of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Due to a misunderstanding in reading through the express docs, my config included a separate `cookieSecret` and `sessionSecret` when I should only be using one shared value.